# Fuji Xerox printer prompts for paper load

Tags: printing, printer

A Fuji Xerox Docuprint CM305df randomly asks to load more paper, even though it has paper in the tray.

It will also ask to select a paper tray when the printer only has one paper tray.

It will then keep printing the one page I was trying to print multiple times until I reset it by continuously pushing clear.

Fuji Xerox technical support advised me to check the settings for page size and it was correctly set for A4. Support then advised that I need to check the paper size every time I print and ensure that it is A4!

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

When you insert paper in the CM305df it prompts you on the front panel for the paper size and type. Make sure they match the driver settings. Just pull out the tray, re-insert it and watch the display. If the front panel settings are correct, check the driver settings and set it to the same. For example, the driver may be set for US Letter, and the loaded paper is A4.

In the case of Word, the size and type are set in Page Setup, as Word ignores driver settings for paper. This can cause problems if you print a document that was created for a different printer.

Comment: On the front panel it says: Load Tray 1 / A4.   Not sure why it's prompting to load tray 1.   Driver: FX DocuPrint CM305 df PS.   Driver Printer Defaults: Paper Size: A4 / Paper Tray: Auto Paper Select

Comment: I asked you to pull out the tray and push it back in. Then watch the front panel display. The printer will indicate the paper size and type it thinks is in the tray. If that does is not the same as in the driver, change it (from the front panel) to match. Also make sure the sliders inside the tray (at the sides and the back) are butted against the paper.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in my previous comment (and answer)? Do this before you start a print job. If printing from Word, check the paper size from Page Setup, not in printer settings.

Answer (score 0):

i finally got to fix this on my Fuji Xerox docuprint cm305, after more than a year i've been having to unload and load paper on the tray every single time. and today after reading this i sorta got to fix it.

i usually use A4, is more common for me. so each time i print it ask me to insert letter paper isntead of A4 in every word or pdf printing.

so the fixing is this.

*** at the printer you select the type of paper on the tray.

in my case. A4, plain.

*** at your computer go to properties of the printer, and click advanced.

in my case. select A4 in the tray 1 section.

and everything will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

in our case someone non-technical had put the paper in the wrong side of the tray so the copier correctly assumed it was empty. Took me half an hour to figure it out!